# How can I get FasterXMLJackson to use @JsonCreator mixin?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization

All,

Can anyone see the error of my ways?

I need custom deserialization, from JSON, to work in Drop Wizard.  I followed some how tos but it isn't working.  The upshot is I don't have available, a default, no-arg constructor.  Instead, I have a factory method. I cannot modify the classes I am attempting to deserialize.  I can serialize to JSON serialize & deserialize to and from XML.  But deserialize from JSON is the stopper.

I have read everything I could find on SO and elsewhere, but nothing prescribed works.

I created a mixin:

```
public class PatientMixin {

    @JsonCreator
    public static ForecastPatient createForecastForecastPatient() {
        return ForecastFactory.eINSTANCE.createForecastPatient();
    }
}
```

In my DW Application.run(...) I did this:

```
<code before>        
environment.getObjectMapper().addMixIn(ForecastPatient.class, PatientMixin.class);
<code after>
```

The above should be enough for Jackson to find my Mixin and call the factory.  Instead I am getting an error:

```
Can not construct instance of forecast.ForecastPatient, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
```

I would have thought I had things mapped properly but apparently not. Also, many of the examples I am reading appear to out of date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is forecast.ForecastPatient an abstract class?

Comment: No it is not abstract it is an interface, of which the factory method returns an  implementation.  ForecastPatient et.al. was generated by eclipse modeling framework.

Comment: Jackson can not instantiate an interface you should tell jackson which implementation you want to instantiate

Answer (score 0):

> By default, Jackson tries to use the "default" constructor (one that
> takes no arguments), when creating value instances. But you can also
> choose to use another constructor, or a static factory method to
> create instance. To do this, you will need to use annotation
> @JsonCreator, and possibly @JsonProperty annotations to bind names to
> arguments
>
> https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations#using-constructors-or-factory-methods

Means that `ForecastFactory.createForecastPatient()` should be annotated with @JsonCreator

Comment: If you mean modifying ForecastFactory to this:

Comment: f you mean modifying ForecastFactory to this: @JsonCreator public ForecastPatient createForecastPatient().  No can do because ForecastFactory is generated code.  Therein lies the rub.

Comment: I think my Mixin is correct and that the problem lies in Jackson finding it.  Funny thing, it recall I made this work once upon a time.

Comment: Do you have implementations of ForecastPatient interface?

Comment: O yes,  That's how EMF works, with factories instead of constructors.  All the EMF code is generated and works faultlessly apart from this situation.

Comment: Try this `environment.getObjectMapper().addMixIn(<implementation of ForecastPatient>.class, PatientMixin.class);` first parameter should be an instantiable class